# ASP.NET Core web application project files are not showing up (the project appears empty even though it is of model control...) Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem in Visual studio 2019 when I create a ASP.NET core web application of type model control the project files are not showing why?

Comment: You can try to uninstall your Visual Studio IDE with the Visual Studio Installer, uninstall every .NET (Core) SDK and .NET (Core) Runtime, and do a fresh Visual Studio install with only the components you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the workload "ASP.NET" isn't installed.

To install this workload :

1. Start "Visual Studio Installer"
2. Click on modify near Visual Studio 2019
3. Check the workload "ASP.NET and web development"
4. Click on "Install while downloading"